# SQL query empty result from php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have this code, that search in my database, but with the php i get empty result, but when i try with phpmyadmin to run the query, it give me results...

```
            // create query
        $query = "SELECT * FROM Moduli WHERE annate LIKE '%$anno%' or annate = 'all'"; 

        // execute query 
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error()); 

        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $lista = $lista."<a class='a' href='iscrivi.php?mode=singup&id=".$idfiglio."&mid=".$row[0]."'><div class='green'>".$row[1]."</div></a>";
        }
```

why by php doesn't print anything?

Comment: That's because you're not printing anything. `echo $lista;` may be? Assuming the fact that you have initialized `$lista` somewhere above.

Comment: Not working, i used echo $lista; but it still print nothing

Comment: Turn on error reporting, add these lines `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your PHP scripts and see if it yields any error or not.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.